# Close a ListBox when lost focus

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor, listbox

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor (C#), trying to close a ListBox  when it lose focus.

My code to listbox is this:

```
@Html.ListBox("nothing", new SelectList(Model.STATUS, "ID_STATUS_CONVENIO", "TXT_DESCRICAO"), new { @id = "idList", @class = "select-multiple w-464", multiple = "multiple", @data_width = "464" })
```

Can somebody help me to do this in jQuery if it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"?  Hide, or close a popup that the listbox is in?  More information is needed.

Comment: You can close a dropdown but not a listbox, last I checked.

Comment: Hide! I need to hide it when lose focus.